# Are there any open source implementation of the snakes or watershed segmentation algorithms?

Tags: open-source, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm working in a graduation project whose goal is to perform a comparative analysis of segmentation algorithms.

I have implemented in C++ a few segmentation algorithms in a undergraduate research project that I have participated (Otsu's method and the EM/MPM algorithm for example).

I am planning to compare the algorithms that I have implemented with the snakes and watershed segmentation. However, it is not my intention to implement those algorithms. So, what I would like to know if there is a open source image processing library that implements those algorithms. It would be better if the implementation were in C/C++, but Java, Python, etc.. are also OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ITK](http://www.itk.org/) might be a solution for you.

Cit.: **Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit (ITK).**  ITK is an open-source, cross-platform system that provides developers with an extensive suite of software tools for image analysis.  Developed through extreme programming methodologies, ITK employs leading-edge algorithms for registering and segmenting multidimensional data. [...]

Despite of its "high level" goals, ITK is a collection of algorithms for segmentation and feature extraction mostly used in medicine. Check for **active contour** when looking for snake-based techniques.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) has an implementation of the [watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#cv2.watershed) segmentation algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Matlab implementation of [Gradient Vector Flow snakes](http://iacl.ece.jhu.edu/projects/gvf/).
And here is a C++ implementation of snakes using [level sets](http://www.insight-journal.org/browse/publication/322)

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken, many open source GIS softwares have focal flow functions. Basically, the implementation of a focal flow involves transportation of a higher value pixel to a lower value pixel.

Spring (INPE´s - brazilian space agency) for sure has an algorithm for that. Terralib (also INPEs) has a complete API for manipulation of spatial objects, which may be what you are looing for.

Sextante´s, is a gvSIG API/add-in that has many raster functions. At least a good framework to start with. Check it out